# Taking of ZF2 Controller Plugin to wrap Facebook Graph Object with

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, zend-framework

I have sussessfully connected with Facebook within my Zend Framework 2 setup. I am looking into collecting comments and comment replies within a given facebook link, say a status update, on a particular page for example my own.

I am stuck on how I can continue with this. Below is a controller plugin I have created:

```
//Use statements ommitted
public function sayHello(){
   $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook(array(
       'app_id' => '*****',
       'app_secret' => '****',
       'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'   
     ));

   try{
      $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access_token}');
    }catch(FacebookResponseException $fre){}
    }catch(FacebookSDKException $fse){}

    $details = $response->getDecodedBody();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($details);
 }
```

Below is an array I get as a result of printing out the decoded body of the facebook array.

```
 Array
 (
    [name] => Luyanda Siko
    [id] => **********
   )
```

I would like an advice on how I can take advantage of the ZF2 Plugin to wrap the Facebook SDK to make calls on link pages where I can:

- Validate the feed link
- Allow my cron script to process the feed links by iterating through to the associated comments and their respective replies?
- And just how I can make my access token last longer than the anticipated 2 hours as mentioned on the docs.

Comment: For the last point: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: Thanks @CBroe for pointing that out. Reading through the page now.... :-)